# What happens to the definition of a filter if we add a "closed under union property"?

Tags: filters

> Let $A$ a set. A non-empty subset $\mathcal {F}$ of powerset $\mathcal {P}(A)$ we say **filter** on the set $A$ if it has the following properties:
>
> is upward closed under inclusion, i.e: $X\in {\mathcal {F}}\land X\subseteq Y\in P(A)\Rightarrow Y\in {\mathcal {F}};$
>
> is closed under intersection, i.e $X\in {\mathcal {F}}\land Y\in {\mathcal {F}}\Rightarrow X\cap Y\in {\mathcal {F}}$

Ok, I want to edit this definition and add also a 3rd property in the property list

$X\in {\mathcal {F}}\land X\subseteq Y\in P(A)\Rightarrow Y\in {\mathcal {F}};$

$X\in {\mathcal {F}}\land Y\in {\mathcal {F}}\Rightarrow X\cap Y\in {\mathcal {F}}$

**3rd property to add:** $X\in {\mathcal {F}}\land Y\in {\mathcal {F}}\Rightarrow X\cup Y\in {\mathcal {F}}$

What happens to the definition of a filter if we add a "closed under union property"?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens, because that was already true: since $X\subset X\cup Y$, we have $X\in\mathcal F\implies X\cup Y\in\mathcal F$ (even if $Y\notin\mathcal F$).

Comment: mm..wait, please. If we read Union and Intersection as logical disjunction OR & logical conjunction AND if we add a 3rd property we add in list another *truth table* (T,T,T,F)

Comment: @Oscar I fail to see how that is relevant to a question on filters of subsets.